# Properly deploying a small Java project

Tags: java, deployment, jar

I'm currently working on a small Java Project (~30 Classes, 5 external libs).
The code accesses resources in the folders src/resources and src/test_resources using getClass.getResouce("/resources/any.file").

Most of these resource files will probably never be touched by a user, but there are also some regular configuration files which are intended to be edited by the end users.

My question now is: How should I be deploying such an application?

Exporting everything into a runnable jar doesn't seem to be a good way, as I don't wanna torture my users and let them unzip the jar for editing the configuration files.

Should I export all of the internal stuff into the jar, and copy the resources directory into a Folder side by side with it? How can I access the resources then?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy the resources folder. It doesn't necessarily need to be side-by-side with the jar file. The key is that you need to put the parent folder of the resources folder on the classpath.

For example, you could copy it someplace like:

```
c:\some\directory\resources
```

Then, when you execute, do something like:

```
java -cp c:\some\directory;c:\some\path\to\your.jar;... your.main.ClassName
```